# A way to post documentation in areas without questions, but for which a valid question does not exist?

Tags: feature-request

So, I ran into this writing a C++ extension for some python code I wrote.  It pertained to accessing and creating ndarrays in C++.

It took me some time to find the information necessary to accomplish this task.  I had to hit a couple of different sites, and about halfway through, I ran into an issue where I felt that I had to hop on SO for a question.

Then, as I wrote down the question, I figured out the answer.  However, the entire process was fairly complex (for a new C++ extension writer)...and I had just written up the whole thing, with links to instructions, a header file, and a how to on the requisite knowledge needed to get it done.  And now I am looking at it, thinking, well, if I could just save this somehow, instead of deleting.

Should there be some kind of peer-reviewed section, where we can submit these kind of questions that start out as questions, but wind up as pretty decent instruction and documentations?  Sort of an alternative to "submit question"; a "submit documentation" or something like that.

Then, the header is linked to google and SO, polished/approved/rejected by the community and available for comments, supplementary posts, etc. Reputation can be conveyed by users who find the post helpful.

This could bypass the problem of fitting every problem/bit of discovery/research/knowledge into a QA format where the user has a question that someone else knows the answer to...

(could also solve the problem of a lot of trivial, but difficult to understand questions getting asked over and over again as otherwise experienced computer programmers move from one language to another)

Comment: Like…a self-answered question, maybe? Why can't this fit into a Q&A format?

Comment: Similar, but bypassing the snark involved in that process; within the scope of the format--no one can dispute the relevance of the question.  They can only justify critique of the content.

Comment: Where is the snark?

Comment: Right there at the negative -1 vote on the comment. @CodyGray

Comment: @bordeo [That's not snark.](https://www.google.com/search?q=snark&rct=j)

Comment: Well, I'm confused. You asked a question on Meta and got a downvote because people think you are [feature-request]ing something that already exists—the ability to ask and answer your own question—which makes it an unpopular [feature-request]. I don't know what that has to do with the "snark involved in [the] process" of a self-answered question, which you claimed was the reason you didn't want to do that. I'm even more confused because *comments* can't get negative votes.

Comment: @CodyGray Check my first comment.  It is discretely different; in the post format I am describing, I don't have to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: @CodyGray He's not requesting an already existing feature, he's requesting the ability to post a post that's not a question, with a separate approval process, and not having an answer.  Essentially they want to be able to post blogs/tutorials/etc. on SO, rather than questions and answers.

Comment: Okay, I oversimplified. The new feature being proposed is something that is *superfluous*, because we already have a better way of handling it that fits nicely into our model. I thought this was a reasonable oversimplification, but I guess not. As this proposal evolves through edited comments, it appears that this is really just a way to get content through whose relevance would be beyond reproach, which seems like a massively stupid idea to me (no offense). If the information you've amassed is actually useful, then it will be fine. Otherwise, we don't want it.

Comment: @CodyGray nor do I have to waste my time qualifying a comment like this in terms of its procedural relevance.  A reduction to a format with a different set of rules is not a valid critique.  Arrays can be conceived of as linked lists, or a graph.  Does not make them either.

Comment: @CodyGray it is not superfluous, because the model that exists over complicates the situation.  Look at how much time we have to resort to this.  

I'd much rather hit posts with a single author that actually work, as a user of SO, than some question, with a barely on target answer that had to be accepted because of peer pressure.  If I could hit that post with ease from google, that would improve the effectiveness of stack.  And, again, this argument is a *massive* cost.

Comment: I…what? You honestly think you should be able to make posts, comments, whatever without defending their relevance? I'm sorry, but I don't know what to say to that. It goes against everything that I hold dear. If you are looking to get your code *reviewed*, you might ask a question on [codereview.se]. Otherwise, if you want to share relevant programming information, then you should be able to fit it into a Q&A format since, as you said, "arrays can be conceived of as linked lists, or a graph". Similarly, useful information can virtually always be presented as an answer to a question.

Comment: @CodyGray That is not what I said. 

The posts are peer reviewed. Like papers.  This is not different than research science. It's not a new idea.  It is only new for SO.  It is more advanced than a wiki.

Comment: All questions and answers here are peer-reviewed. No, it is not a new concept. If you want a "post with a single author that actually work[s]", then you use the self-answer feature. I feel like there is a communication problem here. Not sure how better to explain it, or why I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @CodyGray I consider this feature *worse* than requesting an already existing feature.  Requesting a feature that already exists just means they didn't do their research and realize there was already an existing feature.  Proposing a significant change that would take lots of work, introduce all sorts of issues/concerns, but that adds nothing that already can't be accomplished using other existing features would be doing a lot of harm.  That's why I considered the distinction relevant.

Comment: @CodyGray It isn't a question and answer.

Comment: @Servy you are one man.   I am a user. It is important to me.  I have places to go.  Good luck.

Comment: Shaping your findings into a self-answered Q&A sounds perfectly feasible. In any case, if you refuse to submit them through the kind of peer review done here at Stack Overflow, just post it elsewhere -- in your blog, in a GitHub repository, etc.

Comment: @bordeo The way you described your situation you *did* actually have a question, and then found an answer after formulating your question.  You would have had to go out of your way to transform your question and answer into a stand alone article if this feature existed, rather than the other way around.

Comment: I think that maybe what you are looking for is not something SE is able to provide. Look for a blog, wiki or something else.

Answer (score 6):

> Should there be some kind of peer-reviewed section, where we can submit these kind of questions that start out as questions, but wind up as pretty decent instruction and documentations?

The term "peer-reviewed" suggest that users other than you have some from of editorial control over the content. They can perhaps modify it, or at least comment on the quality of the material. And presumably if it is not quality material, they can disallow it from being visible, yes?

We call that "Q&A". Think about it.

Voting is how we decide whether content is good or not. That's how we exercise editorial control over content. Highly downvoted posts will rarely be seen, outside of bile fascination. We even have the power to edit posts and improve them, if we see fit.

Search engines already index our content, so Q&A works adequately there too. The community has the power to "polish/approve/reject" the title of questions. They are available for comments, and "supplementary posts" can be made by asking additional questions, linking back to the original for reference.

Almost every facet of what you are asking for is what we do now.

> This could bypass the problem of fitting every problem/bit of discovery/research/knowledge into a QA format where the user has a question that someone else knows the answer to...

First, that's not a difficult problem. Creating a question that appropriately shares your knowledge is not hard. Indeed, I would even go so far as to say that, if you cannot formulate a decent question for your solution, you may not understand the problem as well as you might think.

Second, the question part of Q&A is a big part of how search engines can accurately find the right *answers* that people seek. Why? Because people don't look for solutions; they look for their *problem* (well, except for XY cases). So posting a solution without an adequate problem statement will make it more difficult for a user who has a problem but no solution to find.

Think of Q&A like a key/value pair. Users almost always have keys but no values. By linking answers to questions, we make it much easier for people to turn keys into useful values.

What you seem to want is an unorganized, hodge-podge collection of random factoids and code. We call that [Documentation.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) ;)

> could also solve the problem of a lot of trivial, but difficult to understand questions getting asked over and over again as otherwise experienced computer programmers move from one language to another

Yes, that's what the makers of Docs.SO said about that platform. Look how well it's doing at reducing trivial questions.

Comment: I get that.  However, not all discourse is Q & A.

Comment: Ok, documentation.SO--Sounds great, thanks for the heads up.  Regardless, need not be hodgepodge. Sure some smart people can think of something.

Comment: Also, what's with everyone's beef? I asked for a feature that has already been built, is still in beta, and was probably desired long before I piped up.  Further, it was done with great deal of effort. Apparently, it was a pretty excellent idea.

Comment: @bordeo: "*Apparently, it was a pretty excellent idea.*" If the quality you find in Docs.SO is "excellent"... well, there we are then. I have yet to find anything that is more than just minimally competent. And that includes the stuff I added.

Comment: that's a fair opinion.  However, in general, don't we all find out far more in documentation than we do in FAQs?

Either way, there should be a means of saving what we write up, rather than throw stuff away.  Whether it isn't good...well, it is very hard to be good at soccer...there are many people who are very bad.  Does not mean that it is a worthless pursuit nor a bad idea.  

As to hodge-podge organization: not sure you cannot level the same argument against the entire SO substructure.

Comment: @bordeo re: *"I asked for a feature that ... was probably desired long before I piped up"*, as far as I can tell, very few people actively *want* Documentation.SO. More than a few would rather that the SO devs spend more time fixing and improving the *existing* software as opposed to creating new software that doesn't serve a relevant purpose. The rest don't care either way. We're all here for Questions and Answers. This is a Question and Answer site. If you want to supply content in some form other than Questions and Answers, there are many other places you can do that, just not here.